# Написание названия духов: строчная или прописная?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

С большой/маленькой пишется название духов в предложении: "От нее несло шанелью" (не рассуждая о номере духов и глаголе "несло")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русском языке немало слов, образованных от имен собственных. Они приобрели нарицательное значение и пишутся с маленькой буквы.